# Can't connect to iCloud or iTunes on my iPad

Tags: ipad, icloud

I cannot connect to iCloud or iTunes on my iPad anymore. I can connect to the Internet but not iCloud or iTunes. I've tried seeing if I need to update software by going into settings-general-update software but I just get an error saying "unable to check for update. An error occurred while checking for a software update" then another saying "there was an error connecting to iCloud verification failed". Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Control if you can open Settings -> iCloud. At the top there will be your name. Click it and enter your icloud password and reach to your account. Look if any area in payment method  waiting for your update there. (red)